Show convergence of integral $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{P(x)}dx$

Let be $P(x)$ a polynomial of degree $n$,i.e. $P(x):=a_0+a_1x+\dotsc+a_nx^n$. We assume that all zero spots of $P(x)$ are negative. Show that $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{P(x)}dx$ converges absolutely $\iff$ degree of $P(x)\geq 2$.

My approach:
We immediately see that if $\deg (P(x))\leq 1$, then we have something like  $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{a_0}dx$ or  $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{a_0+a_1x}dx$ which obviously doesn't converge. Hence, the direction "$\implies$" is quite easy.
Now we look at the direction "$\impliedby$". First, we notice that we can express $P(x)$ by a product of its zero spots, i.e. $P(x)=(x+z_1)^{r_1}(x+z_2)^{r_2}\cdots(x+z_m)^{r_m}$. Here $r_i$ denotes the multipliciy of the respective zero spot. As $x\geq 1$ and $z_i>0$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ we find the lower bound
\begin{align*}
&P(x)=(x+z_1)^{r_1}(x+z_2)^{r_2}\cdots(x+z_m)^{r_m}\geq (x+z_1)^{r_1}(x+z_2)^{r_2}\\
&\geq (x+z_1)(x+z_2)=x^2+x(z_1+z_2)+z_1z_2\geq x^2\\
&\implies 0\leq \frac{1}{P(x)}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}\text{ for all }x\geq 1.
\end{align*}
We know that $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ converges (absolutely) and so does $\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{P(x)}dx$ by comparison test.

I am not quite sure if this idea is correct as my tutor has deducted points. She criticized that we don't know if $P(x)\geq 0$! But this is clear to me because of the particular nature of the zero spots and $x\geq 1$. Am I missing something else?

The zeroes of $P$ are $<0$, but this doesn't mean that $P(x)>0$ when $x>0$, take $P(x)=-(x+1)$. In fact, $P$ is of constant sign on $[0,+\infty)$, the hypothesis is here to make sure that there is no division by $0$ in the integrand. Now, the absolute convergence means that you have to show that $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{|P(x)|}$ converges iff $\deg P\geqslant 2$. Note that there is a quicker way to prove this : let $\lambda\neq 0$ be the leading coefficient of $P$, then $\frac{1}{|P(x)|}\sim\frac{1}{|\lambda|x^{\deg P}}$, and the integral of the latter converges iff $\deg P\geqslant 2$.

@Tuvasbien, Ah ok thanks for the hint :) Maybe I can fix my proof if I factor out $a_n\neq0$, i.e. $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dotsc+a_nx^n=a_n(\frac{a_0}{a_n}+\frac{a_1}{a_n}x+\dotsc+x^n)$. Then, I apply my idea to $\frac{1}{a_n}P(x)=(\frac{a_0}{a_n}+\frac{a_1}{a_n}x+\dotsc+x^n)\geq0$.

In your inequalities you implicitly supposed that $P$ is unitary, $m\geqslant 2$ and that $r_1,r_2\geqslant 1$ which is not necessary the case, take $P(x)=(x+1)^2$. You can adjust you proof by writing $P(x)=a_n(x+z_1)\cdots (x+z_n)$, eventually with some $z_i$ being equal to each others, in that case $n=\deg P\geqslant 2$, so $|P(x)|\geqslant |a_n|(x+z_1)(x+z_2)$ and you can conclude as you did.
